# How to parse XML using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

I'm using google's Geocoding API but it return XML and I do not know how to parse it.

I'm trying to get the latitude in the XML document that looks like this...

```
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>street_address</type>
  <formatted_address>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>1600</long_name>
   <short_name>1600</short_name>
   <type>street_number</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</long_name>
   <short_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Mountain View</long_name>
   <short_name>Mountain View</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>San Jose</long_name>
   <short_name>San Jose</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Santa Clara</long_name>
   <short_name>Santa Clara</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>California</long_name>
   <short_name>CA</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>94043</long_name>
   <short_name>94043</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>37.4217550</lat>
    <lng>-122.0846330</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>37.4188514</lat>
     <lng>-122.0874526</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.4251466</lat>
     <lng>-122.0811574</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

How can I do that? This is as far as I could get to.

```
string baseURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?";
string fullURL = baseURL  + "address=" + address + "&sensor=false";
Uri ServivrUri = new Uri(fullURL);
WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
byte[] abc = proxy.DownloadData(ServivrUri);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(abc);
XmlDocument xDocument = new XmlDocument();
xDocument.Load(stream);
```

Comment: Try XDocument, it's a bit easier to use than XmlDocument.

Comment: Use XPath. Navigating is SOO much easier.

Comment: @CoryNelson could you point me to some examples. i've tried looking all over the web on how to do this but i just can't seem to put anything together.

Comment: See [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

Then you can use linqToXml

For instance, for getting the latitude, you can try this

```
var latitude = xDocument.Descendants("geometry").Descendants("location")
                        .First().Element("lat").Value;
```

Comment: VS can't find the reference to Descendants(). Is it in the System.Xml.Linq namspace? @Esteban Elverdin

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were using XmlDocument, I updated the answer

Comment: Yeah i was catching onto that from Cory's comments. thank you i'll try this out.