# XML parsing error in c# using visual studio IDE

Tags: c#

I am Facing an Exceptional error as shown below

> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{00C6B4E0-1F82-4D23-9C2D-A1E2386F73FB}\Install\parsing.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\System.Xml.debug.resources.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll
>   An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   The program '[2380] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

The code used for parsing is

```
            string url1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Bangalore&sensor=false";



            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(url1);
            var lat = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("lat", url1)).FirstOrDefault();
            result.Text = (string)lat;
```

I am Facing the error at line **XDocument.Parse(url1);**
Could you please help me to overcome this exception as I am Very new to this field

Comment: Insetad of GETTING the XML from the URL in your url1 variable, you're trying to parse the URL ITSELF - that can't work.

Comment: I used XDocument.Load(url1) method too,but still it threw the same exception.Could you provide me the correct parsing method/code,Thanks

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370101/how-to-parse-xml-using-c)

Comment: There is no definition for porxy.DownloadData() error is thrown.Am I missing any namespace??

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan The link which you specified in that they have used proxy.DownloadData() method,But there isnt any method as such,Kindly Help

Comment: @dheeraj The answers mentioned in that link had approaches to parse google geocode api. The DownloadData() must have been a custom method which wasn't provided. 

The approach provided by Chris Shao in this thread will also work.

Comment: Could you provide me an sample code for parsing?as I am Pretty new to this and chris's code is bit tricky to understand.

Comment: Hi, @dheeraj, read my answer. it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

XDocument.Parse(str) is parse the param `string in parse method`. and the XDocument.Load method means to load `a file in your XAP package`. but you want to load a xml file from web site.
you can send request to the url and read response, then parse it. like this:

```
string url1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Bangalore&sensor=false";
string content = await HttpHelper.GetResponse(url1);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(content);
var lat = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("lat")).FirstOrDefault();
result.Text = (string)lat;
```

the getResponse method here:

```
public async static Task<string> GetResponse(string url)
{
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Dispose();
        response.Dispose();
        return content;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
string url1 = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Bangalore&sensor=false";
string content = await HttpHelper.GetResponse(url1);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(content);
var lat = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("lat")).FirstOrDefault();
result.Text = (string)lat;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider including some information about your answer, rather than simply posting code. We try to provide not just 'fixes', but help people learn. You should explain what was wrong in the original code, what you did differently, and why your change(s) worked.